# VBA Excel - find a cell and format the cells below

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create code to find cells in specific rows that contain 0 which will then format the 8 cells directly below to have a white background and white font.  Basically making the cells not visible.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to change the 8 cells back to their original formatting if the searched in cell has an X.  Any help?  -thanks

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ugnv.jpg)

Unfortunately I am a new user and am unable to display the example image so please click the link above.

Comment: You've said "in specific rows", but not told us how to identify them. How will the code know where to start?

Comment: Please share the code you've written so far.

Comment: Although I've put an answer below, it occurs to me that you could do this with conditional formatting instead.

Comment: The specific rows are 8, 18 and 28.  I figured it out and modified your code example.  Please see below and thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't answered our questions, so the following may not be quite what you want ... but it should be a good start.

```
Sub Hide8CellsBelow0()

    Dim arrayRowNumbers() As Variant
    arrayRowNumbers = Array(2, 12) ' <-- "Specific Rows"

    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim objCell As Range

    For intRow = 0 To UBound(arrayRowNumbers)

        For Each objCell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(arrayRowNumbers(intRow)).Cells

            Debug.Print objCell.Address & " : " & objCell.Value

            If objCell.Text = "" Then Exit For ' <-- Quit the row after finding an empty cell
            If objCell.Value = 0 Then

                With Range(objCell.Offset(1), objCell.Offset(8))
                   'I got the following from recording a Macro, you don't have to remember everything
                   With .Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                   End With
                   With .Font
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                   End With
                End With

            End If

       Next objCell

    Next intRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve!  My apologies for not responding in the past few hours.  I was out on an Earth Day cleanup with my family.

I changed it slightly to look at the "specific rows" which were 8, 18 and 28 and it works as expected.  I then added a second macro to change the font back to previous if an X were present in the rows instead of an 0.

```
Sub Hide8CellsBelow0()

Dim arrayRowNumbers() As Variant
arrayRowNumbers = Array(8, 18, 28) ' <-- "Specific Rows"

Dim intRow As Integer
Dim objCell As Range

For intRow = 0 To UBound(arrayRowNumbers)

    For Each objCell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(arrayRowNumbers(intRow)).Cells

        Debug.Print objCell.Address & " : " & objCell.Value

        If objCell.Text = "" Then Exit For ' <-- Quit the row after finding an empty cell
        If objCell.Value = 0 Then

            With Range(objCell.Offset(1), objCell.Offset(8))
               'I got the following from recording a Macro, you don't have to remember everything
               With .Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
               End With
               With .Font
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .TintAndShade = 0
               End With
            End With

        End If

   Next objCell

Next intRow

End Sub

Sub Show8CellsBelowX()

Dim arrayRowNumbers() As Variant
arrayRowNumbers = Array(8, 18, 28) ' <-- "Specific Rows"

Dim intRow As Integer
Dim objCell As Range

For intRow = 0 To UBound(arrayRowNumbers)

    For Each objCell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(arrayRowNumbers(intRow)).Cells

        Debug.Print objCell.Address & " : " & objCell.Value

        If objCell.Text = "" Then Exit For ' <-- Quit the row after finding an empty cell
        If objCell.Value = "X" Then

            With Range(objCell.Offset(1), objCell.Offset(1))
               With .Interior
                   .Pattern = xlSolid
                   .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                   .Color = 65535
                   .TintAndShade = 0
                   .PatternTintAndShade = 0
               End With
               With .Font
                   .Color = -16776961
                   .TintAndShade = 0
               End With
            End With

            With Range(objCell.Offset(2), objCell.Offset(2))
               With .Font
                   .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                   .TintAndShade = 0
               End With
            End With

            With Range(objCell.Offset(3), objCell.Offset(3))
               With .Interior
                   .Pattern = xlSolid
                   .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                   .Color = 10079487
                   .TintAndShade = 0
                   .PatternTintAndShade = 0
               End With
               With .Font
                   .Color = -16776961
                   .TintAndShade = 0
               End With
            End With

            With Range(objCell.Offset(4), objCell.Offset(4))
               With .Interior
                   .Pattern = xlSolid
                   .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                   .Color = 13434828
                   .TintAndShade = 0
                   .PatternTintAndShade = 0
               End With
               With .Font
                   .Color = -16776961
                   .TintAndShade = 0
               End With
            End With

            With Range(objCell.Offset(5), objCell.Offset(6))
               With .Font
                   .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                   .TintAndShade = 0
               End With
            End With

            With Range(objCell.Offset(7), objCell.Offset(8))
               With .Font
                   .Color = -16776961
                   .TintAndShade = 0
               End With

            End With

        End If

   Next objCell

Next intRow

End Sub
```